# Sporadic loss of connection to internet when connected through corporate VPN

Tags: vpn, wifi, windows-10

I've had this prolonged issue where my internet connection disconnects every now and then, but only when I'm connected through my corporate VPN outside of my office.
Internet connection through WiFi without VPN works fine, as does the connection when I'm in the office and physically connected to my company's network.

When the issue occurs, the active Wi-Fi network begins to toggle rapidly in the connections window in the taskbar. As soon as I disable the VPN connection everything goes back to normal.

We have Windows 10 installed.

Our IT Department seems to struggle with resolving this issue, which is why I hope I can at least get a pointer on what to look at from here. There are a few cases like this with my colleagues as well.

Things we already tried:

- Removed and set up the connection on my laptop
- Removing all but one known Wi-Fi network
- Tried different frequencies on the router
- Different laptops and routers

Any hints or new ideas would be greatly appreciated.

BR
ML

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no details of the software, its configuration nor log entries have been provided. Even if these were available OP appears to be an end-user, not a system administrator, hence only client side information is likely to be available.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm not comfortable with sharing too much on configuration and logs etc. since it's a corporate environment.
As I stated, I was only hoping for rough guidance like "Check DNS" or something of the sort to get it going again with my internal IT.